# Jquery Menu and Logo Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with my logo and menu when it is resized.
If you would load the page and the window width is below 500px and you click on the navicon everything works fine. But if I resize the browser window to a higher width and back below 500px, the logo and the nav will toggle both.

I want my logo to toggle away and the nav to appear, as soon as I click on the navicon, particularly when it is resized.

```js
var menu = $(".nav");
var toggle = $('#navicon');


$(function() {
  $(toggle).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.toggle();
    if ($(window).resize && $(window).width() <= 500) {
      $('#logo').toggle();
    }

  });

});


$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 500) {
    $('.nav').show();
    $('#logo').show();
  }
})
```

```css
#logo {
  width: 150px;
}

.nav {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

#navicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2.5em;
  top: 2em;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #navicon {
    display: block;
  }
  #logo {
    width: 100px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top ">

  <a href><img id="logo" class="img-fluid pull-md-left m-a-0" src="http://www.trainingsrausch.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/TR-logo-CMYK.png"></a>
  <span class="m-r-3" id="navicon">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
          &#9776;
        </button>
      </span>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-md-right m-y-2 m-r-3">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Mitmachen</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I tried to find similar questions and if there are some, please tell me!

Thank you!

Comment: Seems there's an error in your snippet, as the navicon never appears.  Also, to try and clarify what your desired behavior is:  You want the nav to show all the time when the screen is > 500px wide, and at <= 500px, you want to show the logo and navicon, and clicking the navicon should toggle between the logo and the nav?  If the nav is toggled on, and you resize larger and then back to small, do you want to reset the nav to closed, or retain the state that it was in (open/visible)?

Comment: Hey thank you for your hint! :)
I guess the close button of the code snippet covers my navicon, I'll try to fix that!
I guess it would be easier if the nav would be closed again once I scale down below 500px, but I have to try it out.

Comment: Can you please add this codes in jsfiddle.

Comment: Snippet code is not working, fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I updated your code a little bit because Bootstrap is using mobile-first approach.

I think this is that you want:

http://jsbin.com/rufuyebufu/10/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Perfect thank you very much!
Did you use   isLogoShown = ! isLogoShown;  to avoid an infinite loop? Sorry  I'm a newbie :)

Comment: The reason of using `isLogoShown = ! isLogoShown`is that toggle won't work in this situation. Because when logo is showing, menu is hiding or reverse.

In addition isLogoShown = ! isLogoShown means that if isLogoShown is true after new assignment, isLogoShown will be false. This is some kind of manuel toggle.

Comment: This is certainly accomplishing the goal of the question, but (probably in order to be as similar to the original code as possible) it's a lot more JS than you actually need to accomplish the behavior

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider a much lighter way to do this (less JavaScript):

```
$('#navicon').click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menuOn');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 780) {
    $('body').removeClass('menuOn');
  }
});
```

Additional CSS:

```
@media (max-width:780px) {

  .menuOn #logo {display:none;}

  .nav {display:none;}

  .menuOn .nav {display:inline;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ft2o8ra9/